# How to remove red underlines from words in Notepad++?

Tags: html, notepad++

When i write tags like `Html` in Notepad++ , It becomes underlined in red.

I do not know how can i remove it.

Please help thanks

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/593312/how-can-one-turn-off-spell-checking-in-notepad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on

```
Plugins > DSpellCheck > Spell Check Document Automatically
```

Or you could press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>